# mvc4 dropdownlistfor set value from 0 to available stock

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to display a dropdownlist in mvc4 razor view which will have values depending from the items in stock. 
This is the view I have:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
       <div class="panel-group">                   
    @foreach (var m in Model)
    {
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" id="#accordion" data-parent="#accordion" href="#@m.Categories.ID.ToString()">
                        @m.Categories.Name <span class="badge">@m.Categories.ItemCount</span>
                    </a>                     
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="@m.Categories.ID.ToString()" class="panel-collapse collapse">                
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        @foreach (var i in m.Items)
                        {                            
                                using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart"))
                                {
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                @i.Name | Price £@i.Price                               

                                <div class="pull-right">

                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="addButton" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" value="Add"/>                                                                                                                       
                                    @Html.Hidden("ItemId", @i.Id)
                                    @Html.Hidden("categoryId", @m.Categories.ID)
                                    @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)                                        
                                </div>                              
                            </li>                            
                              }
                        }
                    </ul>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>         
    }        
</div>                                  
}
```

Now, for each item in m.Items, there's a property called Stock, so in the view, I want to have some kind of dropdown with values from 0 to Stock value for each item. Any idea how I can populate that specific dropdownlist?

### Update

This is what I'm doing:

In the viewmodel I'm adding one more property:

```
  public List<SelectListItem> StockSelectList;
```

In the controller I'm setting the property:

```
            List<SelectListItem> itemsInStockSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();           
            for (int x = 0; x < itemsList.Items.Count; x++)
            {
                var selectItem = new SelectListItem();
                selectItem.Text = itemsList.Items[x].InStockNow.ToString();
                selectItem.Text = itemsList.Items[x].InStockNow.ToString();
                itemsInStockSelectList.Add(selectItem);                
            }
```

Using this approach I'm setting the values but I need to set for each item in the category, maybe I can use one more property to get the categoryID and the itemID for the SelectItemList?

And in the view I tried this approach:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(k => i.InStockNow, m.StockSelectList)
```

And as I said I'm getting same values for all the items.

Comment: Add the complete code for the controller which shows how you are returning the list and check if you are getting the proper data in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right, this might help.

Sample Model

```
 public class Product
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> StockList { get; set; }
 }
```

Home Controller-> Index Action

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>()
    {
       new Product{ Id=1, Name="Prod1", Stock=20 },
       new Product{ Id=2, Name="Prod2", Stock=10 },
    };

    foreach (var item in products)
    {
       if (item.StockList == null)
       {
           item.StockList = new List<SelectListItem>();
       }
       for (int i = 0; i <= item.Stock; i++)
       {
          var selectItem = new SelectListItem();
          selectItem.Text = i.ToString(); selectItem.Value = i.ToString();
          item.StockList.Add(selectItem);
        }
     }

     return View(products);
}
```

Post action method which will get a List

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(List<Product> products)
 {
   //Do the processing on the list.
   return View();
 }
```

And this is the index view

```
@model   IList<Notsurewhattoname.Controllers.Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
<table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].Name) </td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].Stock, Model[i].StockList) </td>
        </tr>    
    }

</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Sample output

[image: First drop down contains 21 values]

[image: Second drop down contains 11 values]

[image: Quick watch]

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a SelectList

```
var SelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

for (int x = 0; x < i.stock; x++)
{

var selectItem = new SelectListItem() 
selectItem.Text = x;
selectItem.Value = x;
SelectList.Add(selectItem);
}
```

then use this to render

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(i => i.Stock, SelectList)
```

Comment: there will be different stock value for different item, do you think that will make a difference? Thanks

Comment: if this is included within the @foreach (var i in m.Items) it will compute for each item. i just noticed that your using i for your item variable, i will update my code

Comment: This approach doesn't quite work for me, I'm getting the same values for each item.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some WebHelper class for this.

Something like,

```
public static SelectList CreateSelectList<T>(T firstItem, IEnumerable<T> repository,
        string dataValueField, string dataTextField) where T : class
    {
        var items = new List<T>();
        if (firstItem != null)
        {
            items.Add(firstItem);
        }
        items.AddRange(repository);

        var selectList = new SelectList(items, dataValueField, dataTextField);

        return selectList;
    }
```

Then put on ViewBag the select list

```
ViewBag.Itmes = WebHelper.CreateSelectList(null, itemsInStockSelectList, "ItemId", "Text");
```

Add to your Model the ItemIdToSave

And then just use DropDownListFor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ItemIdToSave, (SelectList)ViewBag.Itmes)
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing your for to a foreach

```
List<SelectListItem> ls = new List<SelectListItem>();           
foreach(var temp in itemsList.Items)
{
    ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = temp.InStockNow.ToString(), Value = temp.InStockNow.ToString() });               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your model is this

```
public class TestModel
{
    public List<Tuple<int, string>> Items { get; set; }

    public TestModel()
    {
        Items = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

        Items.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(1, "a"));
        Items.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(2, "b"));
        Items.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(3, "c"));
        Items.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(4, "d"));
        Items.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(5, "e"));
        Items.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(6, "f"));
        Items.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(7, "g"));
    }
}
```

and your controller action is this

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
     var model = new TestModel();
     return View(model);
}
```

and your view is this

```
@model MVC5Empty.Models.TestModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<h2>Test</h2>

<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        <li>@item.Item1 -- @Html.DropDownList(item.Item1 + "ddlvalue", Model.Items.Where(i => i.Item1 <= item.Item1).Select(i => new SelectListItem() { Text = i.Item2, Value = i.Item2 }))</li>
    }
</ul>
```

You should be able to change the .Where clause to fit your business logic needs, in this case Item1 must be less than or equal to the current loop item (note: Tuple is just a way to create a quick object)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that in your code..

```
@foreach (var i in m.Items)
```

'i' has a InStockNow property that should be the max that should show in the drop down.

```
<select name="@Html.NameFor(model => i.InStockNow)"  id="@Html.IdFor(model => i.InStockNow)">
@for (var count = 0; count < i.InStockNow; count++)
      @if (count == InStockNow)
      {
          <option selected="selected" value="@count">@count</option>
      }
  else
  {
      <option value="@count">@count</option>
  }
</select>
```

I'm not sure if the Id I'm selecting for you is the right one but I think you can see how to make the right choices.

I suggest you try a editor template.  You should be able to take all the code in your for each loop and get it to work for a single item.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
    List<SelectListItem> itemsInStockSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();           
    for (int x = 0; x < itemsList.Items.Count; x++)
    {
        var selectItem = new SelectListItem();
        selectItem.Text = itemsList.Items[x].InStockNow.ToString();
        selectItem.Text = itemsList.Items[x].InStockNow.ToString();
        itemsInStockSelectList.Add(selectItem);                
    }
```

If you didn't notice, you're setting `selectItem.Text` two times and never setting `selectItem.Value`.  Fixing this should give you different values for each item.  Once you have the value correct, you should use that information to look up your categoryId and handle the returnUrl in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you have hardcoded list which wont change.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Purpose,
                                new List<SelectListItem> { 
                                 new SelectListItem(){Text="SEX" ,Value="SEX",Selected=false},
                                new SelectListItem(){Text="Male" ,Value="M"},
                                new SelectListItem(){Text="Female" ,Value="F"}

                                }
                            )
```

But looking at your code it looks like you need data from your model a better approach would be as shown by [@Nilesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2514995/nilesh)
Or if you are certain that you'll never get a null value in your model then you can set the data using

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Purpose,
                                new List<SelectListItem> { 
                                 new SelectListItem(){Text=@Model.Name ,Value=@Model.Value}

                                }
                            )
```